# Insert into a PHP associative array with a specific key order

Tags: php, associative-array

Is it possible to insert a new key-value pair into a specific position in an associative array?

For example, let's say we have:

```
$array = [
  'a' => 2,
  'c' => 7,
];
$array['b'] = 5;
var_dump($array); // ['a' => 2, 'c' => 7, 'b' => 5]
```

I would like the new key `b` to be inserted before `c`. I know I can use `ksort` to sort the keys alphabetically in this case after adding the new value. But as I do a lot of insert operations in this array, I don't want to sort all the keys every time I push a new key into the array.

So I'm trying to find a way to insert the value directly into the position I want, but I haven't found at the moment any built-in function to do that. It would be something like [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) but for associative arrays. Maybe it doesn't even exist.

Comment: So `sort` after all pushes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that duplicate. Sorry....